# Regex - Extract string between two expressions, get only last apperance

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Trying to create a regex query that will only return the bolded string:

' Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; en-us; **A2003 Build**/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30 ',

I tried a few ways - got to this option: 
`(?<=;)(.* Build)`

But it returns the following string:

> U; Android 4.2.2; en-us; A2003 Build

Suggestions?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for `(\w+\s+Build)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a lookbehind.
Do this:

`[^;]* Build`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DJbVjw/7)

Match everything other than `;` followed by a *space* and "Build".

If the spaces can be of any type and more than one, do this:

`[^;]*\s+Build`